# GCP logging to both local and cloud logging on IoT device?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, iot

I have some python scripts running on IoT devices (raspberry pis) which I want to keep track of using GCP logging. Originally, my scripts were simply logging to a local file, but now I want to be able to look at my device's logs from the GCP console. I have tried the following:

```py
# Import the Cloud logging library
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging_v2.resource import Resource

LOG_PROJECT = 'project_id'
RESOURCE_TYPE = 'cloudiot_device'
DEVICE_NUM_ID = 'iot_device_num'
DEVICE_REGISTRY = 'registry_id'
LOCATION = 'location'
LOGGER_NAME = 'rpi1-script-logger'

LOG_LABELS = {'project_id':LOG_PROJECT,
              'device_num_id':DEVICE_NUM_ID,
              'device_registry_id':DEVICE_REGISTRY,
              'location':LOCATION}
LOG_RESOURCE = Resource(type=RESOURCE_TYPE, labels=LOG_LABELS)

# prepare a client with the google cloud logging library
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# prepare a handler and attach the client and the resource
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, resource=LOG_RESOURCE)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",'%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# initiate standard python logger and set it up
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# attach the handler so logs are uploaded to the cloud
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

At first I thought this solution would work, but then eventually I stopped getting logs on gcp even though the script was running. After I stopped it, it said something along the lines of "trying to push X pending logs" but immediately failed. It looks like it got stuck and wasn't uploading the logs, so I lost them completely as I also don't have them locally from changing the logger.

As I understand it, the default cloud logging handler is background threaded transport, and I could change it to sync transport as the docs indicate so it uploads the log directly: https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/stdlib-usage.html

However, I´m not sure how to change the transport. Also, I don't want the script to get stuck on trying to upload a log if the connection is lost, ad my script can continue without connection. Is there a better way to upload my device's logs to GCP? or at the very least have my logger save them both to a local file and try to upload them, this way if it gets stuck I can potentially go through my log file and upload them. I even considered saving logs locally as I always had, and have another script trying to upload them separately, but this doesn't sound like a good idea.

Any ideas would be appreciated, I feel like this is an already solved problem but I don't know what that solution might be.

Comment: To get the logs to be stored in a local file you just need to add a FileHandler to your logger. Loggers can generally have any number of handlers attached.

Comment: This is helpful, so I can have multiple handlers then. I will look into this in more detail. Do you know how I can change the transport method? I don't know if this is specific to gcp logger, but the docs I linked to aren't very explicit. I can't tell if it's an option for CloudLoggingHandler, or a different handler instead of that one. It's called transport and handler interchangeably. Thanks so much btw!

Comment: I hope I didn’t misunderstood your question but if you are using Cloud IoT Core and what you would like is to have your logs now in the Console, 
Cloud IoT Core produces two types of logs: audit logs and device logs, and both are available for viewing in Cloud Logging. You just need to enable them.
[Enabling device logging](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/device-logs#enabling_changing_and_disabling_device_logging) - 
[Enabling audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging)

Comment: @Ksign I actually have device logging enabled, and I am using it because I care about the disconnect/connect events. However, in this case I am refering to logs that my application is generating and I would like to have these on cloud logging as well. I believe this is separate? At least from what I can tell on the list of logged events.